# How to wrap all numbers in a file in dollar signs?

Tags: wrap

For example, I have a text:

*bla 1 bla-bla 12 bla-bla-bla 123 end.*

I want to get from it:

*bla $1$ bla-bla $12$ bla-bla-bla $123$ end.*

How do I do this **automatically**?

Comment: hum.... what about if file already contains math, for example, `$3_5$`?

Comment: Probably need some regular expression to ignore this case

Comment: Use a text editor and its regex syntax: `\s+(\d+)\s+` to ` $\1$ `. Or anything like that. What is your problem with such a solution (which you seem to be aware of)?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in all cases. I thought that perhaps there is some more reasonable solution.